# How can I get information from children buttons in gridlayout?

Tags: python, kivy

I need to get information about buttons in gridlayout

```
self.layout = GridLayout(cols = 3)
for _ in range(9):
    self.layout.add_widget(Button)
for _ in self.layout.children:
    print(self.layout.children[_])
```

TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not Button

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the second loop, you are iterating through the children.  Then you are trying to use the child you have, as an index into the array of children.  That won't work.

I believe that you want:

```
print(_)
```

in place of:

```
print(self.layout.children[_])
```

I would also suggest a more meaningful variable name than "_" (and "_" has some special meanings which don't appear to be relevant here, such as "value we don't care about" or, in the interpreter, "last expression").  Something like:

```
for child in self.layout.children:
    print(child)
```